# Using Java Consumer in utility function instead of having to pass it as an argument (But using varargs or similar in replacement?)

Tags: java, java-17

I've been trying to figure out how to use a Consumer in my utility function instead of having to pass it in as an argument.

Here is an example of my code:

```java
// Main class

public ShaderInstance shader;
public ShaderUniform uniformOne, uniformTwo, uniformThree;

@EventListener
public void onRegister(RegisterShaderEvent event) {
   event.registerShader(ShaderInstance.create("path/to/my_shader.fsh"), s -> {
            shader = (ShaderInstance) s;
            uniformOne = shader.getUniform("One");
            uniformTwo = shader.getUniform("Two");
            uniformThree = shader.getUniform("Three");
        });
}
```

This is the utility function i'm trying to implement:

```java
// Utility class

public static void registerShader(RegisterShadersEvent event, String path, Consumer<ShaderInstance> shader) {
        event.registerShader(ShaderInstance.create(path), shader);
    }
```

However, some shaders I want to register may have 1 uniform whereas some may have 5.

I'd like to use varargs or similar (if possible, arguments are final too)

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The utility method is not going to know about the fields in the main class, like `uniformOne`, `uniformTwo` etc. So unless you want to get into reflection territory, you have to take a consumer of some kind, and the caller will use that to assign its fields.

If you want to just make a more general version of what you currently have in `onRegister`, consider using a `Map<String, ShaderUniform>` to store all the uniforms instead, rather than individual fields. The utility method can easily produce such a map from a list of uniform names that you can pass as varargs.

Instead of

```
public ShaderUniform uniformOne, uniformTwo, uniformThree;
```

Declare

```
private Map<String, ShaderUniform> uniforms;
```

And perhaps add a public method that allows getting uniforms by their names.

The utility method can then be:

```
public static void registerShader(RegisterShadersEvent event, String path, BiConsumer<ShaderInstance, Map<String, ShaderUniform>> block, String... uniformNames) {
    event.registerShader(ShaderInstance.create(path), s -> {
        var shaderInstance = (ShaderInstance)s;
        var uniformMap = Arrays.stream(uniformNames)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                     shaderInstance::getUniform));
        block.accept(shaderInstance, uniformMap);
    });
}
```

You'd use it like this in the main class:

```
registerShader(event, "path/to/shader.fsh", (shader, map) -> {
    this.shader = shader;
    this.uniforms = map;
}, "One", "Two", "Three");
```

I'm not sure what library you are working with, but if the `s` in the consumer is always the instance you create in the second argument i.e. `ShaderInstance.create(path)`, then you probably don't need to pass that to the consumer. You can just return that directly:

```
public static ShaderInstance registerShader(RegisterShadersEvent event, String path, Consumer<ShaderInstance, Map<String, ShaderUniform>> block, String... uniformNames) {
    var shader = ShaderInstance.create(path);
    event.registerShader(shader, s -> {
        var uniformMap = Arrays.stream(uniformNames)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                     shader::getUniform));
        block.accept(uniformMap);
    });
    return shader;
}

// Usage:
this.shader = registerShader(
    event, "path/to/shader.fsh", 
    map -> this.uniforms = map,
    "One", "Two", "Three");
```